# Changing CSS with PHP

Tags: php, css

So i read article on css-tricks.com˙(http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) about PHP in CSS and I tried it myself. I'm having problem structuring it. To be specific, i'm using Sql to take image from database and use result as a background image. Like this:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("login", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
```

Then goes my css, i will just write needed ID:

```
#user {
background: url(../img/<?php echo $row['cover']; ?>) fixed;
}
```

And at the end, I close connection:

```
<?php
};

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Everything works except css is outputted double, that is listed twice.Can anyone point the problem? Thanks.

Comment: after `$result = ` run `echo mysql_num_rows($result)` and tell us the output.

Comment: your while loop might be running 2 times(fetching 2 rows)

Comment: It's a 5 year old article. I suggest you use a more recent tutorial for learning. Also, use the MySQLi or PDO extensions with prepared statements and bind variables, rather than learning using the old, deprecated MySQL extension.

Comment: I haven't even looked at the date of article -.- i guess I need to start.

Comment: clearly you have 2 rows with `cover` as an array key...

Answer (score 1):

you're going to create:

```
   background: url(../img/<?php echo $row['cover']; ?>) fixed;
```

for each row returned by the database.
you need to limit the results, either in the sql like:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where userId = $userId");
```

or in the php like:

```
if ($row['userId']==$userId){ ?>
     background: url(../img/<?php echo $row['cover']; ?>) fixed;
<?php}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return as many values as you have in your DB table "users"

If you only want 1 result you need to write

```
"SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1"
```

You dont have a "WHERE" statement for the query?

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE SOME_COLUMN = $your_variable "
```